# custom frame to annotation view mapbox not working

Tags: ios, annotations, mapbox

Im using mapbox and adding a custom annotation view to it. But somehow the annotation view's height is not reflecting.

Here's the code for it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MGLMapView *mapView = [[MGLMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

MGLPointAnnotation *point = [[MGLPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.894368, -77.036487);
point.title = @"Hello world!";
point.subtitle = @"Welcome to The Ellipse.";

mapView.delegate = self;

[mapView setCenterCoordinate:point.coordinate zoomLevel:12 animated:NO];
[mapView addAnnotation:point];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(UIView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView   leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation
{
customAnnotationView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customAnnotationView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 100)];
return view;
}
```

Here the height of view is not reflecting on map.

Answer (score 0):

SMCalloutView, which the Mapbox iOS SDK uses to provide annotation callouts, doesn't dynamically resize based on its child views' height. (At least, it doesn't with how Mapbox configures SMCalloutView by default).

More callout view customization is coming [with v3.1.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases), though!

[`mapView:calloutViewForAnnotation:`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/ios-v3.1.0-pre.3/include/mbgl/ios/MGLMapView.h#L1158-L1167) and [`MGLCalloutView`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/ios-v3.1.0-pre.3/include/mbgl/ios/MGLCalloutView.h) will allow you to completely customize the appearance.